# Copy a file to another while replacing variables in Perl?

Tags: perl, file

I have a problem I am new in Perl and I couldn’t find an answer to my problem.

I have to create a file, copy the content of an other file in this new created file. But the copied file have some variables `$var1` and `$var2`, that I have to replace with the content (interpolate) of those variables in the new file.

I really don’t know how to create, open a file, copy and interpolate in the same time...

Any ideas ?

---

Here is my code :

```
sub my_function ($)
{
 My $var = shift ;
 open (FH, ‘>’, « file1 ») ; #this file is created because it doesn’t exist. 

 Copy($file_to_copy, $FH) ;
  while (my $line = <$FH>)
  {
    if ($line =~ /(Substituethis)/   
    {
      $line =~ s/$1/$var/g;
      print $FH $line;
    }
  }
  close $FH;
}
```

Comment: We need more detail really to give an answer. LIke some code, or sample data, desired output. But I'd suggest the place to start looking is search-and-replace regular expressions, opening and reading a file, and using a search-and-replace hash.

Comment: I have assez my code, i hope it is clear enough! I have an error : readline on unopened filehandle.. maybe because I can not read and write in the same time?

Comment: I'd suggest adding the error you're encountering into your question.

Comment: Sample input and output maybe?

Answer (score 4):

OK, first off - turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. 
There's a couple of syntax errors in your code.

In particular, `FH` - which you are opening - and `$FH` which you are reading are NOT the same thing, and even if they were, ... you can't read/write from the same file concurrently (at least, not like that).

Also - `My` is not the same as `my`, so that'll break too.

You probably don't to declare the sub like that - you're prototyping, and that doesn't mean what you think it means, because perl prototypes aren't the same as other languages.

To do what you want - e.g. replace some 'placeholders' looks a bit like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;   

#define replacement patterns in a hash. (see 'perldoc hash')

my %replace = (
  '$var1' => "a word here",
  '$var2' => "another different word here", 
);

#compile a regular expression that looks for the placeholders.
#note - we need "quotemeta" here because your search patterns include $
my $search = join "|", map { quotemeta } keys %replace;
   $search = qr/($search)/;

print "Using regex for matching:",$search,"\n";


#iterate STDIN (or file specified on command line) line by line
while ( <> ) { 
   #apply pattern matches to current line
   s/$search/$replace{$1}/g; 
   #print current line
   print;
}
```

We use `<>` in the above, because it's one of the easier options for file handling - it means your script works like `sed`/`awk` or `grep` in that you can specify filenames on the command line, or just pipe files to it.

However if you want to open-write you can:

```
open ( my $input, '<', 'filename_here' ) or die $!;
open ( my $output, '>', 'output_filename' ) or die $!;

select $output; #set output source for print location
while ( <$input> ) {
   #apply pattern matches to current line
   s/$search/$replace{$1}/g; 
   #print current line
   print;
}
```

This will read your input file line by line, and write the (transformed) output to the new file.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But I have one last question. I have a lot of datafiles and my variables  $var1 and $var2 change a lot, can I shift my variables in my function through the hash?

Comment: Yeah, sure. You just need to look at _how_ you're wanting to change them. The `$replace{$1}` lookup happens at run time, so you can even dynamically change them as you go.

Comment: Yeah so happy it works perfectly ! Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

This solution works fine for me:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub myfunction () 
{
  open ( my $input, '<', ‘file_name’ ) or die $!;
  open ( my $output, '>', ‘output_file_name’ ) or die $!; 

  my $var1 = "cup";
  my $var2 = "tea";

  my  %replace = (
   '$var1' => "round" ;
   '$var2' => "sweet",
  );

  my $search = join "|", map { quotemeta } keys %replace;
  $search = qr/($search)/;

  print "Using regex for matching:",$search,"\n";

  while ( <$input> )
  {
    s/$search/$replace{$1}/g; 
    print;
  }    
}
```

Comment: You never use `my $var1 = "cup";` and `my $var2 = "tea";`. Maybe you intended your hash `%replace` to look like `'$var1' => $var1` ?

Comment: You should lose the trailing brackets off `myfunction()` - that's a prototype, and they're complicated. (And probably don't do what you want).